# About IOKit framework in iphone

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
   Do any one have idea about IOKit frame work in iphone. Actually i got some information that it was rejected by apple, means if we use this frame work the appstore will not accept the apps. But we can use ambient sensor with IOKit framework. so, any one have an idea about IOKit framework. Please hep me.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though the rejection email tells you everything you need to know.

The rule is: you can only use documented APIs.

IOKit is *not* listed in the iOS documentation. So if you want your app available on the App Store you can't use it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. But i want to find out the light intensity. And some apps also there like Light meter,Pocket Light meter...etc. How can i find it ,i am not getting a way to find it out.

Comment: I would assume that they're using the camera.

Comment: Yes they are using camera only but how to get the values of light intensity.